# Ubuntu 11.10 server monitor goes "out of range" (not grub related)

Tags: 11.10, server, ati, monitor

I'm installing ubuntu server 11.10 on two old servers (asus cuv4x-d, dual p3 1ghz).

For vid cards they have old ATI 4MB PCI cards on the riser.

I can get into the ubuntu server CD fine, install fine and then once I reboot to run the install my LCD monitor goes "out of range". The server should be fine to run headless at this point but I can't start SSH or even ping it so it seems like its stuck doing something.

I followed the post here about editing GRUB for a different resolution I tried a few LCD ones and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you have the exact same problem I had or the solution will work for you as my cards were NVidia but maybe using the same method you can solve your problem. I had my monitors going out of range in the past with 10.04 or 9.11 on many machines with old video cards. The solution was to boot in recovery mode and select low graphics from the menu to boot in graphic mode or use a console. Once booted, I had to change the parameter that was making the monitor go out of range using the NVidia Config tool. In my case it was the vertical refresh freq that I had to set @ 60Hz.